# Can I modify a polynomial to return only multiples of a given number?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm attempting to create a polynomial equation for a project of mine, with a shape similar to the following:

$${3x^5\over500}+{x^4\over25}+x^3+40 x^2+100 x$$

However, one of my goals is to have the equation return integer multiples of the value `100` for all integer values of `x` that are `x>=0`.

For example, the values returned for x=0,1,2,3,4,5 are:

```
{0.000, 141.046, 368.832, 691.698, 1120.380, 1668.750}
```

Whereas I would like it to be multiples of 100.

```
{0.000, 100.000, 300.000, 600.000, 1100.000, 1600.000}
```

I know that I can do something like this:

$$100*\lfloor{50000x+20000x^2+500x^3+20x^4+3x^5\over50000}\rfloor$$

And achieve the desired result, but I wish my equation to be an ordinary polynomial (not relying on floor/ceil/abs functions). Is it possible to create such a polynomial?

---

Thanks! Integer-valued polynomials seems to be exactly what I should be using; the integer linear combination of binomial coefficients below plots a graph that has similarity to mine:

$$100(4{x\choose3}+{x\choose 2}+{x\choose 1})$$

However, it translates merely to a cubic polynomial (which has a slope a bit too steep at the low values of `x` and not steep enough at the high values of `x`).

$${50\over3} x (4 x^2-9 x+11)$$

Although using a higher coefficient (see figure below) restores the desired slope at the high values of `x`, it makes the slope of the low values of `x` even worse!

$$100{x\choose4}$$

It would appear I have to make some kind of compromise. Lowering the restriction, to say multiples of `50` (rather than multiples of `100`), might be required.

Comment: What about the polynomial $1000p(x)$? If any of the denominators is larger than $1000$ you just have to pute more $0$'s in the multiplying factor. This only answers the case where the polynomial has rational coefficients.

Comment: ANY multiples of 100, or certain specific multiples of 100?

Comment: A polynomial taking only integer values is in particular a polynomial in binomial coefficients, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial. Multiplying any such polynomial by 100 gives the kind of polynomial your are looking for, and it is the only way to get such a polynomial.

Comment: Yes, interpolation methods such as Lagrange's are useless in this case.